# How to copy and paste rows conditionally with for loop VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code to attempt to dynamically copy a list to another worksheet. It runs, but instead of copying, it just deletes all of column E on the source worksheet, and doesn't move anything to the destination worksheet. I'm not sure what's going on, any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit

Sub findCells()

Dim topCell As String
Dim leftCell As String
Dim refCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set refCell = ActiveCell

topCell = refCell.End(xlUp).Value
leftCell = refCell.End(xlToLeft).Value

MsgBox topCell
MsgBox leftCell

Worksheets(topCell).Activate

Set sht = Worksheets(topCell)

lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastRow

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Dim cellVal As String
    Dim altCounter As Integer
    altCounter = 31
    Cells(i, 5).Value = cellVal
    If leftCell = cellVal Then
    Dim crange As Range
    altCounter = altCounter + 1
     Let crange = "A" & i & ":" & "G" & i
     Range(crange).Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & altCounter & ":" & "G" & altCounter)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you creating variables within a loop? Move your Dim's from your loop to the beginning of your workbook. It also looks like you are currently assigning Cells(i, 5) within your loop to "" (since CellVal is blank). it looks like what you intended is cellVal = Cells(i, 5).Value. I would also recommend debugging your crange to make sure it is setting properly. I havent seen Let used like that before. I have only seen it used within Class modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the full answer, but you have some errors inside your `For i = 1 To lastRow` loop (and it's too long to write as a comment).

First, fully qualify your `Cells` and `Range` with your defined and set `sht` object.

Second, there is no need to declare your variables (`cellVal`, `altCounter` and `crange`) every time you enter the loop.

Third, to set a range, this `Let crange = "A" & i & ":" & "G" & i` will result with an error, you need to use `Set crange = .Range("A" & i & ":" & "G" & i)`.

Fourth, no where in your code you are giving a value to `cellVal`, so I think your syntax in `Cells(i, 5).Value = cellVal` meant to be `cellVal = .Cells(i, 5).Value`

```
Dim cellVal As String
Dim altCounter As Long '<-- use Long instead of Integer
Dim crange As Range

With sht        
    altCounter = 31
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        cellVal = .Cells(i, 5).Value
        If leftCell = cellVal Then
            altCounter = altCounter + 1
            Set crange = .Range("A" & i & ":" & "G" & i)
            crange.Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & altCounter & ":" & "G" & altCounter)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment as well, but thanks Shai Rado--that was a complete answer and the code worked after I implemented.

However, after I edited to be the below, it stopped working. It doesn't kick up an error, just doesn't copy and paste the rows as it had before.

I'm not sure what's happening, but when I use MsgBox to validate some parts of the code, it looks like it's the loop that isn't functioning. But, without kicking up an error, I don't know why.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findCells()

Dim topCell As String
Dim leftCell As String
Dim refCell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellVal As String
Dim altCounter As Long
Dim crange As Range
Dim rangeToDelete As Range

Set rangeToDelete = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(31, "A").CurrentRegion
    rangeToDelete.Value = ""

Set refCell = ActiveCell

topCell = refCell.End(xlUp).Value
leftCell = refCell.End(xlToLeft).Value

Set sht = Worksheets(topCell)

lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With sht
    .Range("A1:G1").Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A31:G31")
    altCounter = 31
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        cellVal = Cells(i, 5).Value
        If leftCell = cellVal Then
            altCounter = altCounter + 1
            Set crange = .Range("A" & i & ":" & "G" & i)
            crange.Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & altCounter & ":" & "G" & altCounter)
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you are getting your `lastRow` from Column A, and downwards you are running on column E - `cellVal = Cells(i, 5).Value` , is that on purpose ?

Comment: That shouldn't have an effect AFAIK. Both A and E are completely populated.