# VBA code running but not having effect

Tags: vba, excel

The below code was working for the intended purpose: copying some rows from one worksheet to another. But, when I added the parts with rangeToDelete, which is meant to clear out the space I'm copying into before each new running of the code. I'm not sure what's happening, but when I use MsgBox to validate some parts of the code, it looks like it's the loop that isn't functioning. But, without kicking up an error, I don't know why.

```
Option Explicit

Sub findCells()
  Dim topCell As String
  Dim leftCell As String
  Dim refCell As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim cellVal As String
  Dim altCounter As Long
  Dim crange As Range
  Dim rangeToDelete As Range

  Set rangeToDelete = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(31, "A").CurrentRegion
  rangeToDelete.Value = ""

  Set refCell = ActiveCell
  topCell = refCell.End(xlUp).Value
  leftCell = refCell.End(xlToLeft).Value

  Set sht = Worksheets(topCell)
  lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  With sht
    .Range("A1:G1").Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A31:G31")
    altCounter = 31
    For i = 1 To lastRow
      cellVal = Cells(i, 5).Value
      If leftCell = cellVal Then
        altCounter = altCounter + 1
        Set crange = .Range("A" & i & ":" & "G" & i)
        crange.Copy Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & altCounter & ":" & "G" & altCounter)
      End If
    Next i
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of lastrow on entry to the loop?

Comment: Don't use .Value ="" but rather .ClearContents. You're filling those cells with an empty string, not clearing them.

Comment: Or simply like this: `rangeToDelete.Clear`

Comment: Try seeing if adding a dot helps here `cellVal = .Cells(i, 5).Value`.

Comment: I made all the suggested changes. It was @SJR 's suggestions that finally fixed it.

Comment: @VBAnking please copy the code given in the answer to your previous post correctly, I have `cellVal = .Cells(i, 5).Value` with the `.` , see here again... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227892/how-to-copy-and-paste-rows-conditionally-with-for-loop-vba-excel

Answer (score 0):

range.cells used numbers not text use 1 for column A in your code. and also use to clear the contents method as suggested.

Comment: `.Cells` does accept alphabetical column references as well as numerical so `.Cells(1, 1)` and `.Cells(1, "A")` are both correct.